# Django is_popup variable does not exist in base.html

Tags: django

I'm trying to config the django project in vscode and running via debug.
python==3.6.7
Django==2.1.8

When I try to open http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ I am getting the following error, please refer the screen shot below.

[image]

I tried many possible workaround from google, by trying to change logging level from debug to info, but nothing seems to be worked.

I request you to please let me know how to fix this issues.
Thanks in advance.

Error Logs:

```
Exception has occurred: VariableDoesNotExist
    Failed lookup for key [is_popup] in [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {'csrf_token': <SimpleLazyObject: <function csrf.<locals>._get_val at 0x7ff6323e3510>>, 'request': <WSGIRequest: GET '/admin/login/?next=/admin/'>, 'user': <SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7ff632434dd8>>, 'perms': <django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper object at 0x7ff6323b2f98>, 'messages': <django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0x7ff63246cc88>, 'DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS': {'DEBUG': 10, 'INFO': 20, 'SUCCESS': 25, 'WARNING': 30, 'ERROR': 40}}, {}, {'form': <AdminAuthenticationForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(username;password)>, 'view': <django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView object at 0x7ff63246cc50>, 'site_title': 'Django site admin', 'site_header': 'Django administration', 'site_url': '/', 'has_permission': False, 'available_apps': [], 'title': 'Log in', 'app_path': '/admin/login/?next=/admin/', 'username': '', 'next': '/admin/', 'site': <django.contrib.sites.requests.RequestSite object at 0x7ff6323f95f8>, 'site_name': '127.0.0.1:8000', 'LANGUAGE_CODE': 'en-us', 'LANGUAGE_BIDI': False}]
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 850, in _resolve_lookup
        (bit, current))  # missing attribute
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 796, in resolve
        value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 671, in resolve
        obj = self.var.resolve(context)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 875, in eval
        return self.value.resolve(context, ignore_failures=True)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 302, in render
        match = condition.eval(context)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
        bit = node.render_annotated(context)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
        return compiled_parent._render(context)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
        bit = node.render_annotated(context)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
        return compiled_parent._render(context)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
        bit = node.render_annotated(context)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
        return self._render(context)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
        return self.template.render(context)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
        content = template.render(context, self._request)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 106, in render
        self.content = self.rendered_content
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 154, in _get_response
        response = response.render()
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 91, in __call__
        response = response or self.get_response(request)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 91, in __call__
        response = response or self.get_response(request)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 91, in __call__
        response = response or self.get_response(request)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 91, in __call__
        response = response or self.get_response(request)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 91, in __call__
        response = response or self.get_response(request)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 91, in __call__
        response = response or self.get_response(request)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 91, in __call__
        response = response or self.get_response(request)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 78, in get_response
        response = self._middleware_chain(request)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 142, in __call__
        response = self.get_response(request)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 65, in __call__
        return self.application(environ, start_response)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
        self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
        handler.run(self.server.get_app())
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
        self.handle_one_request()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 721, in __init__
        self.handle()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
        self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 348, in process_request
        self.finish_request(request, client_address)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 317, in _handle_request_noblock
        self.process_request(request, client_address)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 238, in serve_forever
        self._handle_request_noblock()
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 213, in run
        httpd.serve_forever()
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 139, in inner_run
        ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading, server_cls=self.server_cls)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 104, in run
        self.inner_run(None, **options)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 95, in handle
        self.run(**options)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 60, in execute
        super().execute(*args, **options)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/home/fs052/Desktop/workspace/tryouts/dj2/dj2/manage.py", line 15, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
        mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
        pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
```

Comment: please try to post error log instead of images

Comment: @c.grey Error log posted

Answer (score 0):

Seems your django installation is corrupt. Try this
`pip install -I django`

Comment: LOL. Sorry too late. Just found it. :D

But may my answer  help others .